# Xpages Fix Indenting on Multiple Categories and Total column on viewpanel

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, xpages, xpages-ssjs

Multiple Category and total column on same viewPanel problem is category indent. This function (Brad Balassaitis code perfect) is not work on bootstrap how can i solve this. http://xcellerant.net/2013/07/10/fix-indenting-on-multiple-categories-in-a-view-panel

Multiple Category and total column on viewPanel screenshot (Last Xpages Extlib Bootstrap Theme and OneUIv3.0.2)
http://i.hizliresim.com/yMzRy9.jpg

```
 function fixViewIndentation(categoryClass) {
 // Get a list of all rows in the view panel.
dojo.query('.xspDataTableViewPanel table tr').forEach(function(nodeRow,  indexRow) {

// Locate the category cells within the context of the view rows
dojo.query('td.' + categoryClass, nodeRow).forEach(function(nodeCat){
// Execute a search on the parent node (row) and remove all cells until data   is found   
var emptyCells = 0;
var countCells = false;
dojo.query('td', nodeRow).forEach(function(nodeTD, indexTD){
  // Start counting when the first category cell is found (this is more for levels after the top-level categorization)
  // Check all non-category cells until a non-empty cell is found
  if (dojo.hasClass(nodeTD, categoryClass)) {
    countCells = true;
  } else if (countCells){          
    if (nodeTD.innerHTML == '') {          
      emptyCells +=1;
      dojo.destroy(nodeTD);
    } else {
      countCells = false;
    }
  }    
  });
  // Add a colspan attribute to the category cell (1 + [# of empty cells])  
  // dojo.attr(nodeCat, 'colspan', 1+emptyCells);
  nodeCat.colSpan = 1+emptyCells;
});
});   
 }
```

Comment: Could you post your code and a screen shot of how it looks? Both should help direct your question to receive a qualified answer. [General question tips for StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: thanks eric, i added screenshot link and function code

Comment: I wrote a similar routine a while back, but using a different approach. I don't have a server with the latest Extension Library on so I don't know it it works with the XPages Bootstrap Theme, but might be worth a try:
http://dontpanic82.blogspot.no/2010/10/xpages-make-categorized-views-behave.html

Comment: Thanks tommy its not work or i had a mistake. can you send me your code on sample.

Comment: Did you also add the partial refresh hijacker (linked below the main code block) to your JS library/the addOnLoad block mentioned at the end of the blog post?